# Find the Ant build files in a directory

Tags: java, ant

There are projects in one of my folder. I need Ant to find the build files of those projects from the console and display. I tried following,

```
/myLibs/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant -find /devel/projects
```

My projects are located in *'/devel/projects'* and ant build files are in inner directories. For instance, one build file is in *" /devel/projects/MOP-release/src/mop_build.xml "* .

Once the above command is run, then it throws error

```
    What? Buildfile: /devel/projects is a dir!  
    Build failed
```

Error is true, and yes it is a directory. Problem is Ant `find` does not work. Let me how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should firstly go to the `/devel/projects` directory and then search using this only:

```
/myLibs/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant -find build.xml
```

All the best.

Comment: Thanks.. but the console shows error " Searching for build.xml ...
Could not locate a build file!
 " . I guess, ant looks for a file named  "build.xml", but my build files do not have such name... Is there a way to figure this

Comment: Is the current directory in your console is /devel/projects

Comment: Yes, I went to the project directory and then execute the ant find command, " /myLibs/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant -find  "

Comment: Same error.   I went to the most immediate parent directory of one of my target xml file. Then Ant could find the file.  I think, Ant can't find the build files in inner directories. I took a look at Ant docs. As I remember, ant does the search from the given location to the root. I want its opposite way.. : given directory to inner child directories..

Comment: Thanks TeeKea. thing is, my problem still doesn't have a fix solution as mentioned in my question, otherwise, I would have already marked it.